# Why php doesn't see the $_SESSION[] array anywhere?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm writing a php code processing a lot of data, sometimes interactively. In my starting php page i call the function `session_start()` before sending any other data to the browser. Then, i put some data into the `$_SESSION[]` array, like this:

```
$_SESSION['something'] = $variable;
```

After, there is a form, what is sent via GET and XMLHttpRequest.

```
getrequest.open("GET", "data_processing.php?var="+onevalue+"&another_var="+twovalue, true)
getrequest.send(null)
```

Another php script recieves the user data from this GET, and there i'd like to use the data stored in `$_SESSION` as well. But `$_SESSION` seems to be empty. I've never used sessions, what is the correct way to make available variables to consequent php scripts?

Comment: Most likely you're losing session in some reason. First step to do - is to make sure that you have the same `session_id()` for both scripts.

Comment: Make sure your XHR endpoint is receiving the PHPSESSID cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution: another script still used the session, so i had to insert session_write_close(); then it works fine. Thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you called `session_start` first?

**See:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: @vizipok on EVERY page that accesses the session variables?

Comment: @vizipok a common mistake that new programmers (by new programmer I mean new to sessions) make is to think they have to call session_start only once in the website.  session_start begins a new session or restarts an old session.